# how to remove vspace between last code line and frame rule in minted?

Tags: minted

There's vspace between last code line and frame rule in inner minted environment. How to remove it?
Compare with `framed`, framed has no space between code and bottom rule.

[image]

Here is MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{minted}[linenos=false,numberblanklines=true,showspaces=false,breaklines=true,frame=lines,framesep=8pt,framerule=0.3pt]{java}
globalMemStoreLimitLowMarkPercent * globalMemStoreSize
\end{minted}


\begin{minted}[linenos=false,numberblanklines=true,showspaces=false,breaklines=true,frame=lines,framesep=0pt,framerule=0.3pt]{java}
globalMemStoreLimitLowMarkPercent * globalMemStoreSize
\end{minted}

\FrameSep=0em
\begin{framed}
globalMemStoreLimitLowMarkPercent * globalMemStoreSize
\end{framed}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is your objective is to just adding a top and bottom lines to the `minted` env? In my experience the build-in frame scheme in `minted` is not robust. You could use other frame package (e.g. tcolorbox)

Comment: @Tom yes, I just want to add top and bottom rule with equals vspace between code and rule above and bottom.

Comment: If for this simple task, you could even add the rule manually without using frames. I think it would be really hard to remove that space without changing the code in the `minted` package.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @Tom's advice. I tried to combined `tcolorbox` and `minted`, and now I have solved my problem. Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[chapter]{minted}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbuselibrary{listings,minted,skins,breakable}

\AtBeginDocument{%
    % args: options, language, caption, label, codes block
    \newtcblisting[blend into=listings,list type=lstlisting]{mlisting}[4][]{
    enhanced,
    listing engine=minted,
    minted style=manni,
    minted language=#2,
    minted options={frame=none,fontsize=\small,
        linenos=true,numberblanklines=false,numbersep=5pt,
        baselinestretch=1.2,breaklines,breakanywhere,autogobble,mathescape,#1},
    listing only,
    listing remove caption=false,
    size=title,breakable,
    frame hidden,boxrule=0pt,
    arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,
    boxsep=0pt,before skip=10pt,after skip=10pt,
    top=2pt,bottom=2pt,left=10pt,right=10pt,
    colback=yellow!5,
    overlay={\begin{tcbclipinterior}
        \path[draw=black!90,line width=0.4pt,line cap=round]
        (interior.north west)--(interior.north east)
        (interior.south west)--(interior.south east);
        \end{tcbclipinterior}},
    coltitle=black,
    attach boxed title to top center={yshift=2pt},
    boxed title style={empty,size=minimal,colback=white},
    fonttitle=\small,
    title={#3}, label={#4}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\lstlistoflistings
\clearpage

\chapter{Listing test}

\begin{mlisting}[]{java}{Java example}{lst:lst1}
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
\end{mlisting}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{mlisting}[linenos=false]{python}{python example}{lst:lst2}
def _merge():
    while left and right:
        yield (left if left[0] <= right[0] else right).pop(0)
    yield from left
    yield from right

return list(_merge())
\end{mlisting}

\begin{mlisting}[]{java}{Java example}{lst:lst3}
// some code here.
\end{mlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks really good!